# How do I check if a word starts with a capitalized letter, and place a condition if so?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to do a program that "reads in a line of text the user inputted and replaces all four-letter words with the word 'baby', and if that four-letter word's first letter is capitalized (e.g. Love), it must be replaced with the word 'Baby'. The program must continue unless the user enters 'exit'."

I already accomplished the part where the program is supposed to replace all four-letter words with the word "baby", and the program should only terminate if the user enters "exit", **but I can't seem to figure out how can I check if the word starts with a capitalized letter and if so, replace it with the word "Baby" instead.**

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> input)
    {
        if (input == "exit")
        {
            break;
        }

        std::stringstream ss(input);
        int count = 0;

        while (ss >> word) 
        {

            if(word.size() == 4)
                word = "baby";

                std::cout << word << ' ';

                ++count;

        }
    }
}
```

======================================

To be more clear:

If I enter `You are my love`, it outputs `You are my baby`, correct.

But if I enter `You are my Love`, it should output `You are my Baby`, but I can't seem to figure out how. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I finally know how to do the code now, and it perfectly works! Thanks to everybody who helped. :)

Comment: Check [`std::isupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ mentioned a way, another way is check word[0] is between 'A' and 'Z' or not.

Comment: @khôinguyễn: you ahve to be careful with that approach since it's not strictly portable.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right, only for ASCII.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem reduces to inspecting the first letter of `word`: you can use `word[0]` to do that, having checked that `word` has a non-zero length.

What you *can't* do is use `if (word[0] >= 'A' || word[0] <= 'Z')` since that makes assumptions about the *encoding* used by your plaform. (EBCDIC for example does not have the upper case letters in one block!)

What you *can* do is make use of `std::isupper`, and allow it to use its default locale. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper.

Putting this together, use `if (!word.empty() && std::isupper(word[0]))`, nothing that due to the short-circuitting nature of `&&`, the right hand argument is only evaluated if `word` is not empty.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a newbie at c++. Where am I supposed to place the `std::isupper` ?

Comment: @D.B. check std::isupper(word[0]), if it true then word[0] is capitalized.

Comment: @khôi nguyễn How do I check for all the words, and not just the first word `word[0]`?

Comment: @D.B. `word[0]` is not first word, it's `word`'s first letter.

Comment: @Zereges nevermind, silly me. I'm finally understanding how to do it now.